# Configureing php to use with apache

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I am using Apache 2.2.3 server on RHEL5. In my system, php is installed (PHP 5.1.6). I placed a simple php script

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

in my /var/www. However, when I start my server (it starts fine) and go to the php page, it does not show anything. My local machine has ubuntu installed, where I can see the file properly.

Following the information provided here (http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html), I did following things:

1. Added following lines to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

   ```
   LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
   AddHandler php5-script  .php 
   AddType text/html   .php
   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source phps
   ```
2. restarted httpd,

   ```
   service httpd restart
   ```

But I still don't see any results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The closing tag of your test script lacks the question mark: `?>` instead of `>`.

Comment: You claim "But I still don't see any results". Well, what _do_ you see? There must be something, 'cause the universe does not simply stop to exist...

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Actually, the php file has no problem, I have tested it in my local machine.

Comment: That means at least it is not treated as a plain text page. That is good. I suggest you try the same script on php cli to make sure php is fine.

Comment: Right click, View source (or Ctrl+u) .. do you see your PHP code?

Comment: BTW: you sure you want to use php-5.1? It is more than outdated.

Comment: @lostsource: true actually, that slipped me :-)

Comment: I tried View source, it shows a blank page, I saved it, it created a blank "test.php" file (that was the name of my file). Btw, this is my full result of php -v 

PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2012 06:20:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

Comment: And, what does that test script output on cli?

Comment: Look at your Apache error log (usually in /var/log/apache/error.log) .. there might be something useful there, also the instructions mention editing '/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf' not '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' .. you could try loading a non-existing module just to make sure the config file is actually being read

Comment: This is a bit surprising, I don't have a file called '/var/log/apache/error.log' or '/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf'. 
@arkascha I am not familiar with php cli, but will try it out.

Comment: @lostsource, after I added the previous lines, I get the message 'Starting httpd: [Sat Nov 10 04:54:04 2012] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping' while i restart httpd. This means the config file is actually being read.